# How can I get OpenJPA to work with for joined inheritance strategy?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, annotations, openjpa

I'm unable to get a joined inheritance strategy working with OpenJPA 2.1.0 and a Java EE app running on Glassfish 3.1.
Here are my JPA annotations:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_account")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "account_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    public abstract class UserAccount implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "merchant")
    @DiscriminatorValue("MERCHANT")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id")
    public class Merchant extends UserAccount {
    ...
```

and this is the exception I get:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not map discriminator value "MERCHANT" to any known subclasses of the requested class "my.app.model.UserAccount" (known discriminator values: [UserAccount]).
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.ValueMapDiscriminatorStrategy.getClass(ValueMapDiscriminatorStrategy.java:98)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.InValueDiscriminatorStrategy.getClass(InValueDiscriminatorStrategy.java:121)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.Discriminator.getClass(Discriminator.java:398)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.SuperclassDiscriminatorStrategy.getClass(SuperclassDiscriminatorStrategy.java:63)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.Discriminator.getClass(Discriminator.java:398)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:397)
```

It seems my subclass discriminator is not getting picked up. I've tried various combinations including listing all my entities in persistence.xml but to no avail. I've also tried omitting the @Discriminator annotations altogether (which aren't obligatory for joined strategy), this at least allowed my to query the subclasses diretly but broke polymorphic queries.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you solve it? If so, how?